# Finding % of Revenue contribution per marketplace SQL

Tags: sql

I am looking to find how much each marketplace contributes to Revenue. As I understand the over() function is the best way to do so. The code I currently have is:

```
select brand_name, region, sum(s.revenue) as ltm_revenue
from table1
where date > '2021-08-01'
group by brand_name, region;
```

What I'm looking for is to add another column which has how much the region contributes to the total revenue per brand_name

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 0):

Building on your query, you can indeed use `over(partition by ...)` to calculate the revenue contribution:

```
with revenue_per_region as (
   select brand_name, region, sum(revenue) as ltm_revenue
   from table1
   where date > '2021-08-01'
   group by brand_name, region
)
select 
   brand_name, 
   region,
   ltm_revenue,
   ltm_revenue/sum(ltm_revenue) over (partition by brand_name) as revenue_contribution
from revenue_per_region
```